# AJAX send JSON array not binding in controller

Tags: arrays, json, ajax, controller, asp.net-core-mvc

I have an issue that my controller is not receiving the JSON array I send via AJAX as it's not binded to a model/ViewModel

This is what I am sending

[image]

You can see the array has a string id and text. Therefore I have tried adding my own model with the properties in:

[image]

And then trying to catch the array in the controller:

[image]

However you can see it's coming in the POST as NULL.

In Chrome -> Dev tools -> Network tab. The Form Data is

[image]

What am I missing?

Thanks

Comment: In Chrome Dev Tools, can you see the json payload in the Network tab?

Comment: Funny that, I probably was doing that as you wrote the message..

In the Network section under headers, the Form Data is "Undefined"

Comment: Scrap that, its because I took out `JSON.stringify`

Comment: you send an array but the action expects a single object.

Comment: @Nkosi even with `List<headingstee>` it comes back as NULL

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An array is posted but the action expects a single object.

Also for model binding from the body of the request you can use `[FromBody]` attribute

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult InsertMasterTemplate([FromBody]headingstree[] tree) {
    //...
}
```

Reference [Model Binding in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/model-binding?view=aspnetcore-2.1)

ensuring to include:

```
contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",`
```

in the AJAX method,